# Dealing with LocalDate and Months names

Tags: java, localdate, leap-year

I have a .txt file, which I import into my Java program, for example `("2012.12.01")`. I get the month (interesting, because I never use the `getDayOfMonth().name();` part, and even so it writes the names, not the numbers (`JANUARY` instead of `01` or `1`). So I tried to identify if the month is February or not. But even if it's true, the `if` returns `false`. 
Maybe it is because the month is never equal to String.

```
for (Changes c : list) {
                int Year = v.getDate().getYear();
                Month month= v.getDate().getMonth();
                int Day = v.getDate().getDayOfMonth();
                if (Year%4==0 && month.equals("FEBRUARY") && Day==24) 
                    leapDay = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
Month.FEBRUARY.equals(month)
```

`"FEBRUARY"` is a `String` literal, and `month` is a `Month` instance which makes them incomparable.

There is [`LocalDate#isLeapYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isLeapYear--), so your condition could be reduced to

```
if (v.getDate().isLeapYear()) {
    // handle a leap year
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I guess because the Month never equal to String.

Yes, exactly. You could either compare the `Month` value with `Month.FEBRUARY`, or just check the value returned by `getMonthValue`. Note that your day-of-month part is currently wrong though - and your year check is incorrect for years divisible by 100. Fortunately, you don't need to know that part - the date can *only* be February 29th in a leap year anyway. I'd use:

```
LocalDate date = v.getDate();
if (date.getMonthValue() == 2 && date.getDayOfMonth() == 29) {
    // Leap day handling
}
```